# GetDayLightChanges from System.Timezone.CurrentTimeZone

Tags: c#, timezone

I am puzzled by this problem.

I have a console application which needs to take the daylight changes and put them in the DB.

```
var daylight = System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(dateofOffset.Year); 
var start = daylight.Start.ToString(); 
var end = daylight.End.ToString();
```

The dayLight object will have valid dates if I put the timezone on my machine to Eastern Time, but if I switch the timezone of my machine to any other timezone then the result of the function for start and end dates is 1/1/0001.

My application runs on windows 7. I am changing  the timezone through "Change time zone" on Date and Time option on windows.

Am I missing something totally obvious ?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the timezones you're switching to use daylight saving time?  If not GetDaylightChanges(int year) will return a default DayLightTime object with the values you're seeing

Comment: I am changing the timezone on windows through Time Zone Settings

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but daylight is one word.  The L should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running this method will help clarify:

```
public void ListDSTAdjustmentRules()
    {
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        foreach (var timeZoneInfo in tz)
        {
            var adjustments = timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules();
            foreach (var adjustmentRule in adjustments)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "TimeZone: {0} SupportsDST: {1} DateStart: {2} DateEnd: {3} Delta: {4}",
                    timeZoneInfo.DisplayName, timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime, adjustmentRule.DateStart,
                    adjustmentRule.DateEnd, adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta);
            }

        }
    }
```

As mentioned in my comment above, if a TimeZone that does not support DST then GetDaylightChanges() will return a default object where the values are DateTime.MinValue and Delta is a TimeSpan with 0 ticks.

Comment: It is not true that GetDaylightChanges returns invalid date for all time zones. It returns min value dates for timezone that don't